# Client Validation error does not prevent submit & ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, yii

I use Yii client validation to validate some inputs and when there is an error in the user input, Yii client Validation does not prevent submit and does not prevent ajax request.
I use grid widget "carvw-grid" and when user click submit button its make ajax request to update "carvw-grid" content with results. I want to prevent submit and ajax request when there is a client validation error.

here is my script code:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.search-button').click(function(){
$('.myloading').show();
$('.myshow').hide();
$('.myresult').slideUp().delay(3000).queue(function() {
    $(this).show();
    $('.myloading').hide();
    $('.myloading').addClass('myshow');
    });
    });

$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('carvw-grid', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
");
```

and here is my form

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'carvw-form',
    'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
    'method'=>'get',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'focus'=>array($model,'OWNER_ID'),
    'clientOptions' => array('validateOnSubmit'=>true, 'validateOnType'=>true),

)); ?>
```

and here is my submit button

```
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('search',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
</div>
```

and here is my grid

```
<?php 
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'carvw-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),

    'columns'=>array('CAR_COMPANY_NAME','MODEL_YEAR',
        'CAR_COLOR_NAME',
        'USING_TYPE_NAME',array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));

 ?>
```

How can i prevent submit and ajax request on client validation errors?

Comment: I've never touched Yii, but would I be way off-base to question the line `'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,`?

Comment: i didnt use ajax validation, i only  use client validation, the ajax request used to get the result of search.

Comment: do you call `$form->error($model, 'field')`?  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#c5223

Comment: yes, i call it, and not problem in the validation!, the problem that the client validation error does not prevent submit and ajax request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to use afterValidate function instead of binding submit event. Into CActiveForm.clientOptions array add following element:

```
'afterValidate' => 'js:afterValidate',
```

In your javascript file:

```
function afterValidate(form, data, hasError) {
    if (!hasError) {    
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update('carvw-grid', {
            data: $(this).serialize()
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, but Sadly, this didn't help to solve my problem.

Comment: Do you have live site where we can check what's going on? Also what's your Yii version?

Comment: `afterValidate` is working fine. Also if you specify id of input manually, you should specify inputID for `$form->error`. Check this: [link](http://pastebin.com/LaKygQcJ). Hope this help.

Comment: problem solved with your code with slight modification i use data: $('.search-form form').serialize() instead of $(this).serialize() and it works like clockwork, thank you very much, you are amazing :)